# Python equivalent of ruby rspec's "skip" and "pending"

Tags: python, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, pytest

I'm coming from ruby to python. With ruby's rspec, I am used to using [`skip`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples) and [`pending`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/pending-examples) to denote tests which should be skipped / cannot currently be executed.

What are the equivalents in Python?

Answer (score 2):

Python's [`pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) allows:

- [Skipping test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions), eg:

  ```
  pytest.skip("unsupported configuration")
  ```
- [`xfail` for tests which are expected to fail](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#xfail-mark-test-functions-as-expected-to-fail), eg:

  ```
  pytest.xfail("waiting for foo to be fixed")
  ```